# Surfnorm lacking some datas in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure

i'm trying to use Surfnorm to optain normal verctors on a surface on a specific point, my problem is that this function doesn't seem to show me the components on the X, Y and Z axis of the vectors it draws but only the position of the point of the object the vector originates from
using the Nx, Ny and Nz matrices from the [Nx,Ny,Nz] = surfnorm(___) use of surfnorm, any idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.